# How to increase execution-speed of AutoIt code?

Tags: autoit

I want to start two programs simultaneously.

- One has a graph which displays expected actual output-line (and after execution it shows another output-line).
- The other has some application in it.  This second program has to be started at the same time the first one (with graph) is.

But there is an unwanted delay (microseconds) between both programs getting started. Is there a way to speed up AutoIt execution?

Comment: Not use AutoIt. Or design you program so that it can deal with time delays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Longer Explanation: A single computer can never execute two programs at the exact same time. Even Multitasking is just switching between programs so fast that there seems to be the effect of running simultateously, but in fact they work sequentially, not parallel. And even with multiple processor cores you will have the os scheduler run on one single core, so you could with lots of programming effort and timer events probably make it run two processes each on one dedicated core executing a given similar entry point at the same clock time. But that won't help you much as your output would still be processed by a single graphics card and a single mainboard with the same interrupts shared for each core... So for your specific question, it's not possible.

You could actually try to use `AdlibRegister` to run a specified Function in the future... but it will also pause the main scripts execution... AutoIt is not capable of running several functions simultaneously. As far as I understand it, it's not even designed to do so as it is an interpreted scripting language.

You could use another language capable of threading to perform what you want to.

Anyways, your `Run(...)` function will not wait for the termination of execution as `RunWait` will. So the gap between the two `Run` calls should be pretty small. Having said that, a question for further discussion might be: What do you want to achieve exactly and how do you achieve your goal without the help of AutoIt? Because your clicking speed is most likely less fast than your calls to some functions... You could ask another question being more specific about your very problem. But then provide some example code, please ;-)

And using this simple example code, you can actually prove that even when using two `Run` calls, you can't be sure that the programs will actually appear in the given order. At least on my computer (Win7 64Bit, Quad Core i5 3.1GHz, 4GB RAM) these lines will produce some output where the Window of the second run call appears before the window of the first... Approximately 5-15% of the time.

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
For $i = 1 To 50
   $pid1 = Run("notepad")
   $pid2 = Run("notepad")

   $firstWin = WinWait("Notepad")
   $winProcess = WinGetProcess($firstWin)

   If $winProcess == $pid2 Then ConsoleWrite($pid1 & ", " & $pid2 & "; " & $winProcess & @CR)
   ProcessClose($pid1)
   ProcessClose($pid2)
Next
```